# Fill NAs with either last or next non NA value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, na, zoo

I am trying to fill NA values in a column with other non-NA values within the same group in R.
So my data looks something like this:

```
df
       id year pop
1  E1 2000  NA
2  E2 2000  NA
3  E2 2001  NA
4  E2 2003 120
5  E2 2005 125
6  E3 1999 115
7  E3 2001 300
8  E3 2003  NA
9  E4 2004  10
10 E4 2005  NA
11 E4 2008  NA
12 E4 2009   9
13 E5 2002  12
14 E5 2003  80
```

And I want NA values to have either the last non-NA or the next non-NA value of `pop` within the same group of `id`. To look something like this:

```
    df.desired
   id year pop
1  E1 2000  NA
2  E2 2000 120
3  E2 2001 120
4  E2 2003 120
5  E2 2005 125
6  E3 1999 115
7  E3 2001 300
8  E3 2003 300
9  E4 2004  10
10 E4 2005  10
11 E4 2008   9
12 E4 2009   9
13 E5 2002  12
14 E5 2003  80
```

I tried different things with both `zoo::na.locf()` and `dplyr::fill()` but I keep having two main issues: 1. I get errors because entire groups only have NA (like `id == "E1"` here) and 2. I can only choose either the last or the naxt non-NA value.
These are some examples of what I've tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
    df.desired <- df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
      arrange(year)%>%
      mutate(pop_imputated = pop)%>%
      fill(pop_imputated)%>%
      ungroup()


df.desired <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(year)%>%
  mutate(pop_imputated = zoo::na.locf(pop))%>%
  fill(pop_imputated)%>%
  ungroup()
```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: why row 11 is 9 but row 10 is 10?  Do you mean in case of 2 NAs, one to be filled forward and one backward?  What if 3 NAs consecutive in between?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an answer that would match your expected output **exactly**: it will impute to the nearest non-missing value, either upward or downward.

Here is the code, using a spiced up version of your example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df = structure(list(id = c("E1", "E2", "E2", "E2", "E2", "E3", "E3", "E3", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E5", "E5"), 
                    year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2003L, 2005L, 1999L, 2001L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2018L, 2019L, 2002L, 2003L), 
                    pop = c(NA, NA, NA, 120L, 125L, 115L, 300L, NA, 10L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9L, NA, 8L, 12L, 80L), 
                    pop_exp = c(NA, 120L, 120L, 120L, 125L, 115L, 300L, 300L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 12L, 80L)), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))

fill_nearest = function(x){
  keys=which(!is.na(x))
  if(length(keys)==0) return(NA)
  b = map_dbl(seq.int(x), ~keys[which.min(abs(.x-keys))])
  x[b]
}

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, year) %>%
  mutate(pop_imputated = fill_nearest(pop)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 18 x 5
#>    id     year   pop pop_exp pop_imputated
#>    <chr> <int> <int>   <int>         <int>
#>  1 E1     2000    NA      NA            NA
#>  2 E2     2000    NA     120           120
#>  3 E2     2001    NA     120           120
#>  4 E2     2003   120     120           120
#>  5 E2     2005   125     125           125
#>  6 E3     1999   115     115           115
#>  7 E3     2001   300     300           300
#>  8 E3     2003    NA     300           300
#>  9 E4     2004    10      10            10
#> 10 E4     2005    NA      10            10
#> 11 E4     2006    NA      10            10
#> 12 E4     2007    NA       9             9
#> 13 E4     2008    NA       9             9
#> 14 E4     2009     9       9             9
#> 15 E4     2018    NA       9             9
#> 16 E4     2019     8       8             8
#> 17 E5     2002    12      12            12
#> 18 E5     2003    80      80            80
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

As I had to use a `purrr` loop, it might get a bit slow in a huge dataset though.

**EDIT:** I suggested to add this option in `tidyr::fill()`: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1119. The issue also contains a tweaked version of this function to use the `year` column as the reference to calculate the "distance" between the values. For instance, you would rather have row 15 as 8 than as 9 because the year is much closer.

Comment: @AntVal Glad I could help :-) You might also be interested in the function linked in my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to change the `.direction` attribute of the [`tidyr::fill`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html) function? You can use `"downup"` (first downwards, then upwards), or viceversa `"updown"`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(pop_imputated = pop) %>%
  fill(pop_imputated, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 14 x 4
   id     year   pop pop_imputated
   <chr> <int> <int>         <int>
 1 E1     2000    NA            NA
 2 E2     2000    NA           120
 3 E2     2001    NA           120
 4 E2     2003   120           120
 5 E2     2005   125           125
 6 E3     1999   115           115
 7 E3     2001   300           300
 8 E3     2003    NA           300
 9 E4     2004    10            10
10 E4     2005    NA            10
11 E4     2008    NA            10
12 E4     2009     9             9
13 E5     2002    12            12
14 E5     2003    80            80
```

It looks similar to your desired output

Comment: Well-done! I really like your solution. I've never used `fill` but it appears to offer some interesting flexibility.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Thanks to the tidyverse programmers who implemented this option!   We only need to know it :D

Comment: it seems that OP wants to fill with the nearest (so that row 11 should be 9), which is unfortunately not supported by `tidyr::fill()`

Comment: @DanChaltiel OP said "either the last non-NA or the next non-NA" and I interpreted as if it doesn't matter for them. Maybe they will give more detail

Comment: @RicS I agree that the title lacks a bit of clarity, but the expected output is quite clear.

Answer (score 3):

library `runner` has a built in [function `fill_run`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runner/vignettes/built-in_functions.html) which may also be used

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(pop = runner::fill_run(pop, run_for_first = T))
#> Warning in runner::fill_run(pop, run_for_first = T): All x values are NA
#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [5]
#>    id     year   pop
#>    <chr> <int> <int>
#>  1 E1     2000    NA
#>  2 E2     2000   120
#>  3 E2     2001   120
#>  4 E2     2003   120
#>  5 E2     2005   125
#>  6 E3     1999   115
#>  7 E3     2001   300
#>  8 E3     2003   300
#>  9 E4     2004    10
#> 10 E4     2005    10
#> 11 E4     2008    10
#> 12 E4     2009     9
#> 13 E5     2002    12
#> 14 E5     2003    80
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you were looking for. I filled all `NA` values with the last non `NA` values in a group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(pop, ~ coalesce(.x, last(.x[!is.na(.x)]))))


# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   id [5]
   id     year   pop
   <chr> <int> <int>
 1 E1     2000    NA
 2 E2     2000   125
 3 E2     2001   125
 4 E2     2003   120
 5 E2     2005   125
 6 E3     1999   115
 7 E3     2001   300
 8 E3     2003   300
 9 E4     2004    10
10 E4     2005     9
11 E4     2008     9
12 E4     2009     9
13 E5     2002    12
14 E5     2003    80
```

Comment: why using `across` and not `mutate(pop = coalesce(pop, last(pop[!is.na(pop)])))` Is there any specific reason to do so?

Comment: They both lead to same results with this grouping. Just a personal choice and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution uses `nalocf`(NA last observation carried forward); as it operates top-down, we first need to re-`arrange` the dataframe so the first `pop`value is non-`NA`:

```
library(zoo)
df %>%
  arrange(desc(id)) %>%
  mutate(pop = na.locf(pop))
   id year pop
13 E5 2002  12
14 E5 2003  80
9  E4 2004  10
10 E4 2005  10
11 E4 2008  10
12 E4 2009   9
6  E3 1999 115
7  E3 2001 300
8  E3 2003 300
2  E2 2000 300
3  E2 2001 300
4  E2 2003 120
5  E2 2005 125
1  E1 2000 125
```

We can of course reinstitute the original order:

```
library(zoo)
df %>%
  arrange(desc(id)) %>%
  mutate(pop = na.locf(pop)) %>%
  arrange(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `na.approx` accepts `approx` arguments (see `?approx` and `?na.approx`) we can use `na.approx` with `method = "constant"` and `rule = 2`.  Also sort the data back to the original order if you want exactly the output shown in the question.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(year)%>%
  mutate(pop_imputated = na.approx(pop, method = "const", rule = 2, na.rm = FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(id, year)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
   id     year   pop pop_imputated
   <chr> <int> <int>         <dbl>
 1 E1     2000    NA            NA
 2 E2     2000    NA           120
 3 E2     2001    NA           120
 4 E2     2003   120           120
 5 E2     2005   125           125
 6 E3     1999   115           115
 7 E3     2001   300           300
 8 E3     2003    NA           300
 9 E4     2004    10            10
10 E4     2005    NA            10
11 E4     2008    NA            10
12 E4     2009     9             9
13 E5     2002    12            12
14 E5     2003    80            80
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "       id year pop
1  E1 2000  NA
2  E2 2000  NA
3  E2 2001  NA
4  E2 2003 120
5  E2 2005 125
6  E3 1999 115
7  E3 2001 300
8  E3 2003  NA
9  E4 2004  10
10 E4 2005  NA
11 E4 2008  NA
12 E4 2009   9
13 E5 2002  12
14 E5 2003  80"
df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```